# UITextView Problem with scrolling text

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview, frame, uitextviewdelegate

[image]

I am using UITextView in above screenshot. But problem is when I am trying to scroll text its getting out of screen of UITextView. I have tried by reducing TextView frame but doing that its reducing UITextVIew Frame...

How can i maintain same UITextView height and my text also not go out of the frame ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to change the table view content size:

```
[textView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
```

Set width and height so that the whole text view fits inside that text view.
Also check that the scroll is enabled inside of the text view; if it is not then set it:

```
textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Hope it helps! ;D

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting isScrollEnabled of UITextView to TRUE?